# How to give option to users View on Google map from the embedded map in your web page?

Tags: google-maps

I am using google map api version 3 to embed a google map of some place. I have seen on some websites there is a label on google map with the pinned location's name & option of View on Google Map.

Answer (score 1):

```
https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place
  ?key=API_KEY
  &q=
```

The following URL parameter is required:

q: defines the place to highlight on the map. It accepts a location as either a place name or address. The string should be URL-escaped, so an address such as "City Hall, New York, NY" should be converted to City+Hall,New+York,NY. (The Google Maps Embed API supports both + and %20 when escaping spaces.)